# X509V1CertificateGenerator emigrate to X509v1CertificateBuilder

Tags: java, x509certificate, bouncycastle

Hello I am using the class `X509V1CertificateGenerator` to generate a certificate of the type `X509Certificate`.
now the class `X509V1CertificateGenerator` is deprecated and the recommanded alternative is `X509v1CertificateBuilder` but I do not know how to do the Migration.

Here is the Code:

```
X509V1CertificateGenerator certGen = new X509V1CertificateGenerator();

// set the necessary X500-fields
X500Principal dnName = new X500Principal("CN=MyServerName");
certGen.setSerialNumber(BigInteger.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()));
certGen.setIssuerDN(dnName);

// expire-date
Calendar expireDate = Calendar.getInstance();
certGen.setNotBefore(expireDate.getTime());

// expires in 25 years
expireDate.add(Calendar.YEAR, 25);
certGen.setNotAfter(expireDate.getTime());

certGen.setSubjectDN(dnName); // note: same as issuer
certGen.setPublicKey(pair.getPublic());

// set the right signature-algorithm ->RSA/DSA
if (this.algorithm)
    certGen.setSignatureAlgorithm("MD5withRSA");
else
    certGen.setSignatureAlgorithm("SHA1withDSA");

// generate the X509-certificate
X509Certificate cert = certGen.generate(pair.getPrivate(), "BC");
```

What should I do to do the Migration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this extracted from keycloak [CertificateUtils](http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?source_dir=keycloak-master/common/src/main/java/org/keycloak/common/util/CertificateUtils.java)

```
SubjectPublicKeyInfo subPubKeyInfo = SubjectPublicKeyInfo.getInstance(pair.getPublic().getEncoded());
X509v1CertificateBuilder builder = new X509v1CertificateBuilder(
       subjectDN, 
       serialNumber, 
       validityStartDate,
       validityEndDate, 
       subjectDN, 
       subPubKeyInfo);

AlgorithmIdentifier sigAlgId = new DefaultSignatureAlgorithmIdentifierFinder().find(signatureAlgorithm); 
AlgorithmIdentifier digAlgId = new DefaultDigestAlgorithmIdentifierFinder().find(sigAlgId); 
ContentSigner contentSigner = 
      new BcRSAContentSignerBuilder(sigAlgId, digAlgId)                   
               .build(PrivateKeyFactory.createKey(pair.getPrivate().getEncoded())); 

X509CertificateHolder holder = builder.build(contentSigner);

X509Certificate cert = JcaX509CertificateConverter().getCertificate(holder);
```